# How to sort on element having multiple occurrences in XML using cts:index-order in MarkLogic?

Tags: sorting, marklogic, marklogic-8

Let's assume I have bunch of XMLS with structure as defined below.

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <name>Dixit</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </child1>
    <child2>
        <name>Singla</name>
        <age>45</age>
    </child2>
</root>
```

`CTS search query` I have written returns me the entire document

I want to sort the documents by `<name>` element of `<child2>`.

I have defined the `cts:index-order` for `<name>` element but the documents are getting sorted by element `<name>` of `<child1>`.

How can I sort the documents by `<name>` element of `<child2>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a path range index on `child2/name`, and use that for [`cts:index-order`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order).

Here are some details on how to create a path range index using the Admin UI: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_54948

[`cts:index-order`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order) takes a `cts:reference` as a parameter. To use a path range index, you need a [`cts:path-reference`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-reference).

```
cts:index-order( cts:path-reference("/root/child2/name", ()) )
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply it's very helpful.
Please help me with an example, I am not able to figure out how can I use the `created path range index` in `cts:index-order`

Comment: Thanks grtjn.
How can I implement the same in search:search API?
What would be the syntax in search options?

Comment: Got the Answer...
ML do not support `path-index` for `sort-order` (`search:search API`) but we can achieve the same with `fields`

Comment: Don't believe the documentation, you *can* use `path-index` inside `sort-order`. I have used it several times. I thought I reported it internally, but maybe I forgot..

Comment: It's working.
But facing another problem when I am defining `path-range-index` having `namespace`, I am getting an error.
`SEARCH-BADORDERBY: (err:FOER0000) Indexes are required to support element, element-attribute, json-property, or field sort specifications.`
Seems like if `path-index` xpath contains `namespace prefix` it's not recognising as a valid `path-index` for sort-order.

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: Perhaps best to file a new question, so that you can provide more detail on specifics, and I don't have to provide the answer in a comment.. ;)

Comment: okay, Here is the link to the question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846322/path-index-is-recognized-by-ctspath-reference-when-xpath-contains-namespace-pre