# path index is recognized by cts:path-reference when xpath contains namespace prefix

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

If an element exists more than one places in a XML.
Then it was difficult to sort the data on a particular element (by default docs will be sorted on the first element).

I was able to solve this problem by defining a `path-index` and passing it to `cts:path-reference` query.

But if the `xpath contains` a namespace prefix(namespace is defined for the xml) then `cts:path-reference` is not able to find the `defined path-index`.

I am getting the below error.

`SEARCH-BADORDERBY: (err:FOER0000) Indexes are required to support element, element-attribute, json-property, or field sort specifications`

Not able to understand why I am getting this error.
Please help!

Comment: Have you defined 'path-index' in admin page correctly? Have you used XPath like '/h:path/h:to/h:xmlElement' in path-index configuration? where h is the namespace prefix

Comment: same is the case with cts:reference(), path expression should have namespace prefix while using it.

Comment: @rishabhv66 Yes I have defined the xpath the way you have mentioned and also created a `path-namespace` for it in admin console.

Comment: try creating a global namespace. That will be available throughout the application through Admin Page [8001]. I bet you haven't defined the namespace globally.

Comment: Yes I haven't defined at App server level, Will try and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Some good practices around path indexes:

- Make sure you use the exact same path expression string both when declaring the index, and when using it, including identical prefixes
- Declare the prefixes are path namespaces at the least, optionally at app server level instead
- [cts:path-reference](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-reference) takes a third parameter with which you can pass in namespace bindings

HTH!